# How to specify the login_required redirect url in django?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a view function:

```
@login_required
def myview():
    # do something
    # respond something
    pass
```

How can I specify the exact URL for this view function to be redirected?

Comment: Is there anything like logout_required in django?

Answer (score 109, accepted):

LOGIN_URL in your settings

Reference:

- [LOGIN_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-url)
- [LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#login-redirect-url)

Answer (score 81):

you can do this in your view works fine for me without declaring in settings.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/example url you want redirect/') #redirect when user is not logged in
def myview(request):
    do something
    return something #returns when user is logged in
```

Comment: This is correct and worked perfectly but always prefer using LOGIN_URL because of login url changed in future you may need to change lots of places

Comment: Its better to use the url name instead of the path as it can change anytime.`re_path(r"login$", LoginView.as_view(template_name="registration/login_form.html"), name="player_login")` then the decorator is `@login_required(login_url="player_login")` Ofcourse it superseeds the login_url and login_url_redirect in settings. Thanks for sharing.

Comment: It would have been better if you'd have added where to import `login_required` from.

Answer (score 16):

default login url is: '/accounts/login/'

if you want to change it then go to settings.py

```
LOGIN_URL='/path/to/url'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL='/path/to/redirecturl'
```

Answer (score 11):

this from documentation should be helpful:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator

```
@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def my_view(request):
    ...
```

Comment: Let say I tried to go to http://mysite/home from a non-authenticated user, this login_url tries to get to the login page from http://mysite/home/login_user.html. The problem with  this is that it keeps the /home/ path and so does not work. Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

Go to your setting.py
You can add this anywhere in your settings.py file but i prefer to place it at the bottom.
LOGIN_URL = '/login/'

NOTE: '/login/' is the URL segment that brings the user to the login page. The complete URL is similar to this "myexample.com/login/".

Answer (score 2):

We have two approaches, first is the best practice for code maintenance in the future, and the second will be a hassle when the URL for login changes

First approach

in setting.py import reverse_lazy, and set LOGIN_URL to the login namespace

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
LOGIN_URL = reverse_lazy('login')
```

In your views, you import login_required and require login before each function

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required()
def view_name(request):
    pass
```

Second approach 
This approach is not reliable since you won't have a defined variable holding your login URL namespace

In your views, you import login_required and require login before each function

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required(login_url='/path/to/login/')
def view_name(request):
    pass
```

In both cases what is static is you will have to import login_required in views

Answer (score 1):

you can also take url from view

for example

```
path('login/', login_view, name='login_name'),
```

then decoratorwill be

```
@login_required(login_url='login_name')
```

Comment: I tried this and it didn't work for me

Comment: if you want to use the name attribute, you have to use the `django.urls.reverse` function, i.e. `@login_required(login_url=reverse('login_name'))`

Comment: ERRATUM: Don't use the reverse in the `@login_required()` or you'll lose an hour debugging :( It generates a "circular" issue and crashes (i.e. urls are not recognised anymore).

Answer (score 1):

Django 4+ makes this very easy.

In urls.py make sure you have a path with a name you can reference:

```
path('login/', login_view, name='login_name'),
```

Then in settings.py, all you need to do is add this to the bottom:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'login_name'
```

Now all your `@login_required` decorators will automatically send anyone not logged in to your login page. If you change that url in the future, the settings.py file stays updated since it's referencing the name and not the absolute url path.

I recommend *against* doing any of the 'path/to/url' approaches above since as soon as you change that path you then need to change everything. Reference the 'login_name' once in your settings.py file, and be done forever.

Answer (score 0):

## In django  project settings

add below code

```
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'path/to/url'
```

and then import this LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL in your views and add

```
`@login_required(login_url=LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL)`
```

to the top of your views you want to restrict it will work

Answer (score 0):

My signin/signup page was ignoring the `?next=...` part of my path, and just redirecting to the home page, '/'.

By including:
`<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ request.GET.next }}">`

After my submit button, the redirect worked properly.