# Apply django authentication for all views

Tags: python, django, django-views

I am trying to implement Django basic authentication for all of the views in my `views.py` file. Although I can add the authentication code snippet in every view, but it will not be easy to apply this to upcoming views. Is there any way that every view in my `views.py` will automatically check for the authentication?

#### `views.py`

```
def mgmt_home(request):
    ##############################################################
    # This code is repetitive
    ##############################################################
    if request.user.is_anonymous:
        return redirect("/login")
    ##############################################################

    test_name = Test.objects.all()[0].test_name

    metadata = {
        "test_name": test_name,
    }
    return render(request, "mgmt_home.html", metadata)
```

Is there any way where I can avoid this `repetitive` code in all of my views?

Answer (score 1):

you can use 'login_required()' decorator or 'LoginRequiredMixin' class from django authentication.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/

[How to specify the login_required redirect url in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578882/how-to-specify-the-login-required-redirect-url-in-django)

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 options:

1. from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

You can add this @login_required() decorator to your every view and it will automatically redirect a user to the login page (or whatever page you want to send the user to) any time your user is not logged in.

2. This option, in your case, I would not recommend, as this might be an overkill and not required for your simple problem. The solution is to create a custom Middleware and add your code to it, and then, of course, add the Middleware to the Settings.py file. This way, each time your views run, your Middlewares will run prior to that. In fact, that's the purpose of Middlewares. They are designed to reduce redundancies and problems exactly such as yours.

Answer (score 1):

Create a middleware.py file anywhere on your python path. Add the below codes to your created middleware.py file

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse_lazy

def redirect_to_login():
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse_lazy('users:login'))


class AuthPageProtectionMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response
        # One-time configuration and initialization.

    def __call__(self, request):
        # Code to be executed for each request before
        # the view (and later middleware) are called.

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        if not request.user.is_admin:
            return redirect_to_login()
    else:
        return redirect_to_login()

    response = self.get_response(request)

    # Code to be executed for each request/response after
    # the view is called.

    return response
```

**NOTE**

You can replace the redirection URL with your application-specific one.