# inactive page after signin to social media on django allauth

Tags: django, django-allauth

Iam trying to develope a website that use socail media for authentication based on google and facebook.
I used django-allauth library for it.
but I have problem with this when user create account or signin via google. after successfully signin return inactive page. I want to redirect to my home page
there is my custom model

there is my custome models

```
class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    USERNAME_FIELD = "email"

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=100, unique=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    profile_pic = models.ImageField(
        null=True, upload_to=image_path_generator, blank=True
    )
    total_storage = models.FloatField(
        default=20, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(20.0)]
    )
    used_storage = models.FloatField(
        default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0.0), MaxValueValidator(20.0)]
    )
    phone_no = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    user_key = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True, null=True)
    joined_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)

    two_auth = models.CharField(
        choices=twoAuth_choices, max_length=20, default=twoAuth_choices[1][1]
    )

    files = models.ManyToManyField(
        "fileuploads.NewFile",
        related_name="file_owner",
    )
    folders = models.ManyToManyField(
        "folders.Folder",
        related_name="folder_owner",
    )
    # required
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    last_login = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    is_admin = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_superadmin = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ["username", "first_name", "last_name"]
    objects = AccountManager()
```

i have also setup my settings.py to like this

```
#  SOCIAL CONNECTION
SITE_ID = 1
SOCIALACCOUNT_LOGIN_ON_GET = True
ACCOUNT_AUTHENTICATION_METHOD = "email"
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True
ACCOUNT_USERNAME_REQUIRED = False
ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = "none"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = logout_url
```

could you please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to wrap each view with the @login_required decorator and set the login_url argument equal to the home.  Something like this:

`@login_required(login_url='/example url you want redirect/')`

There is another SO thread for this here:  [How to specify the login_required redirect url in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578882/how-to-specify-the-login-required-redirect-url-in-django)