# Django app profile page still showing after logging out

Tags: python, django

I am trying to set up a profile page for users. It works when I logout, but I need to setup the condition to be redirected to the login page if the user is logout

views.py:

```
def login_user(req):
if req.method == 'POST':
    form = AuthenticationForm(data=req.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        user = form.get_user()
        login(req, user)
        return redirect('http://127.0.0.1:8000/')

else:
    form = AuthenticationForm()

return render(req, 'loginpage.html', {'form': form})


def logout_user(req):
    if req.method=='POST':
        logout(req)
        return redirect('home')


@login_required
def profile_page(req):
    user = req.user
    user_profile, created = UserProfile.objects.get_or_create(cur_user=user)
    return render(req, 'profilepage.html', {'user': user, 'user_profile': user_profile})

@login_required
def edit_bio(req):
    if req.method == 'POST':
        new_bio = req.POST.get('bio')
        user_profile = req.user.userprofile
        user_profile.bio = new_bio
        user_profile.save()

return redirect('profile_page')
```

urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.homepage, name='home'),
    path('signup/', views.signup, name='signup'),
    path('login/', views.login_user, name='login'),
    path('profile/', views.profile_page, name='profile_page'),
    path('profile/edit/', views.edit_bio, name='edit_bio'),
    path('logout/', views.logout_user, name='logout'),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

How can I implement that

Comment: Do you mean you want the user to be redirected to the login page after the logout event specifically? or you want to protect all pages only for logged in users?

Answer (score 0):

This question is the duplicate of [How to specify the login_required redirect url in django?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3578882/how-to-specify-the-login-required-redirect-url-in-django).

The solution is to set the `LOGIN_URL="/url to redirect/"` in `settings.py` or provide it to the decorator:

```
@login_required(login_url='/url to redirect/')
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me

```
@login_required(login_url='login_user')
```

you can also mention in settings.py file

```
LOGIN_URL='your_url'
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).